# D3 circle pack example - open in new window

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269‚:

[image]

I want to recreate this code but I am going to have a bunch of menu items to click on.
When the user chooses, the item they want, then I want to open the bubble in a new window.
THis is the code that opens it in the same frame currently.  Is there a way to change this code to open the page in a new window:

```
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
```

Comment: The code you've posted only adjusts the height of the current frame. I'm not clear what you're trying to do -- once a menu item is selected, open a new window with a visualisation? If so, this has really nothing to do with D3.

Comment: Lars, sorry I am just not good at this stuff and this is the solution I came up with:                          `  var newWindow = window.open('');
   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   var svg = d3.select(newWindow.document.body).append("svg")`

Comment: It will be much easier if you design the visualisation without thinking about opening new windows first. It sounds like having separate pages would be a better solution for you anyway.